# How to insert a column inside a dataframe based on vector?

Tags: r, dataframe

For example I have a dataframe `data1` with these columns:

```
A B C D G T Q Y U J N
```

And I have another dataframe `data2` with rows as follows:

```
A B C M
D G K T
Q F Y U
J W E N
```

Based on the above dataframe, I should have a column `M` after column `C` and before column `D`. I also should have a column `K` between columns `G` and `T` etc..

Therefore I want to use `data2` to fill up the missing columns in `data1`. If I do that successfully, `data1` should be :

```
A B C M D G K T Q F Y U J W E N
```

My code so far:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(data2))
{
for(column in 1:ncol(data2)){
element = data2[row,column]
for(column in 1:ncol(data1))
{
if(element!=colnames(data1)[column])
{

}

}

}
```

I'm not sure where to go with my code now, I don't think that it is an efficient code to begin with. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `t`ranspose the second dataset, convert to a `vector` and use that as column names after assigning the columns that are not in the original data to `NA`

```
nm1 <- c(t(data2))
nm2 <- setdiff(nm1, names(data2))

data1[nm2 ] <- NA
data1 <- data1[nm1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, what is "data" though? I'm assuming it's either data1 or data2

Comment: @Alonso23  It is a typo, `data1`